# MPMoviePlayerController playing movies in reverse (backwards) is not smooth in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am developing an iPhone application where I need to reverse a video playback. I am currently using XCode 4.2. I am trying to play a movie in reverse with the MPMoviePlayerController.
But when it plays in reverse it is not as smooth as playing it forward. It becomes a bit choppy and is not at all smooth. The following is my code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
//code for initializing the movie player
MPMoviePlayerController videoPlayer = 
[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:"URL"];
self.videoPlayer = videoPlayer;
[videoPlayer release];
self.videoPlayer.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.videoPlayer.initialPlaybackTime = -1;
self.videoPlayer.shouldAutoplay=NO;
[self.videoPlayer prepareToPlay];


//code for initializing the button 
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[button setTitle:@"Reverse" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[button addTarget:self 
action:@selector(reverseMovie) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 40);

[self.view addSubview:button];
}

-(void)reverseMovie{
[self.videoPlayer setCurrentPlaybackRate:-1.0];
}
```

What could be the possible solution to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to do the same in AVFoundation. I had to work it quite a lot before I managed to get it to work.

What I did was to generate image, reverse the order, put them in to an assetWriter, export the video and then play it.

You can download my code here: https://github.com/mikaelhellqvist/ReverseClip

Comment: File it under issues on GitHub. I will have a look at it.

Comment: Mike your sample code crashes here any suggestions? - BOOL appended = [assetWriterPixelBufferAdaptor appendPixelBuffer:pixelBuffer withPresentationTime:presentationTime];

Comment: I haven't had any problems with it. Do you have a log? You could create an issue on github.

Comment: Found your issue on GitHub now. Will answer you there.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out buddy. Do tell what those width and height parameters mean and if we need to worry about them in our code for different sizes and length of videos

Comment: That should work in the future for you. That's the output size of the generated clip. What I did was dividing the source clip width and height with 2. So you might want to change (before I fix that) FRAME_WIDTH and FRAME_HEIGHT to something like sourceClipFile.width/2, sourceClipFile.height/2.

Comment: If you generate a clip with full dimensions (same as the original) you could run in to memory issues.

Comment: I get memory warnings from your code...any suggestions on how to fix those please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with AVPlayer

```
 avPlayer.rate=-1.0f;
```

This will set the rate to -ve,hence playing the video in reverse smoothly. :)