# Black frame when changing rate of AVPlayer item

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am reading a 30s MP4 video with AVPlayer. When it comes to the end, I would like to keep play it backward, then normally, then backward, and so on...

It is working fine with the following code, but I am having a black frame every time I am playing the video again in the other way.

Here is my code is `viewDidLoad`:

```
    let playerVideoURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "my_video", withExtension: "mp4")!

    self.backgroundPlayer = AVPlayer(url: playerVideoURL)
    self.backgroundPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.backgroundPlayer)
    self.backgroundPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize
    self.backgroundPlayer.volume = 0
    self.backgroundPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .none

    self.backgroundPlayerLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(self.backgroundPlayerLayer, at: 0)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                           object: self.backgroundPlayer.currentItem)
```

And here is the method called each time the video finishes playing:

```
func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: Notification) {
    self.backgroundPlayer.rate *= -1
}
```

Thank you if you have any idea. I think it might be because the video is not buffered instantly when I'm changing the rate, but I didn't find what I am looking for in the AVPlayer documentation...

Comment: Interesting discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310945/mpmovieplayercontroller-playing-movies-in-reverse-backwards-is-not-smooth-in-i and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11902203/reverse-video-playback-in-ios